# Scala syntax error

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, syntax-error

Why line 19 is error and 21 is not error.
It is the same error in Eclipse and in Intellij Idea.
If I change line 19 to myAccount.print than it OK.

I suppose this is bug ?!

```html
bject scalatest extends App {
  class BankAccount {
    var balance = 0
    def deposit(amount: Int) {
      if (amount > 0) balance += amount
    }
    def withdraw(amount: Int): Int =
      if (0 < amount && amount <= balance) {
        balance -= amount
        balance
      } else error("insufficient funds")
    def print = println(balance)
  }
  
  val myAccount = new BankAccount
  myAccount deposit 100
  myAccount deposit 100
  myAccount withdraw 50
  myAccount print
  myAccount deposit 1000
  myAccount print
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the compiler warning about postfix operators will tell you, they're sometimes ambiguous for parsing. The final line is fine because it's at the end of the block, but it's not sufficiently clear to the compiler that lines 19-20 aren't supposed to be read as `myAccount.print(myAccount).deposit(1000)`. If you put a semicolon after the `print`, `myAccount print;`, it should work.